# How get SQL error message using ServerConnection SMO In C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

When executing an SQL statement using (**ServerConnection** and **Server**), I cannot get the original SQL error. Just a generic message. **SqlConnection** and **SqlCommand** are useless because my SQL statements contain **"GO"**.

I'm using:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

My C # Instruction:

```
        try
        {
            string command = File.ReadAllText(@file);
            ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(cnx.ip, cnx.user, cnx.password);
            Server server = new Server(conn);
            server.Databases[cnx.datebase].ExecuteNonQuery(command);
            conn.Disconnect();
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CreateFileLog( ex.GetBaseException().Message, file, outputFolder);
            ...
        }
```

Error when running directly on SQL Server:

[IMAGE IN SQL DIRECTLY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwslC.png)

Catch C # exception error:

[IMAGE IN C# EXCEPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzYKH.png)

Questions:

1. Why don't I get the same output from SQL Server in C #?
2. How to get the number of rows affected, if "Database.ExecuteNonQuery()" is of type Void?

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` - executes a statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected, it indeed does return how many records are affected. If you want the actual error from `sql` you could create an output param with having a `BEGIN TRY/BEGIN CATCH` statement in your `sql` and then set this new output param to `ERROR_MESSAGE`... Also, it doesn't help when we can't see what the query looks like, this would definitely help us in helping you. Could you please post what the sql query looks like?

Comment: You know that GO does not work in SMO either, right?

Comment: Does not work ? Why is there no error when running with (ServerConnection and Server)? With (SqlConnection and SqlCommand) already presents erro.

Comment: @Ericnano what is value of er.Message? or er.InnerException?

Answer (score 0):

1. Why don't I get the same output from SQL Server in C #?

> Have you check the if there are some inner exception? Sometimes some
> exceptions have lost of inner exception and may the error message you
> might want to see is inside it.

2. How to get the number of rows affected, if "Database.ExecuteNonQuery()" is of type Void?

> You can add an output parameter on your command then set the number of
> rows affected on it.

UPDATE for Question#2
[SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-ver15) is mostly use for managing sql databases. If what you intended is for managing then ExecuteNonquery has no way to return rows affected. But is what you are doing is for transaction processing then much better if you use ADO.Net.

I hope this helps. Happy coding.